# Bacterial Conjugation/Horizontal Gene Transfer -- how does the plasmid exchange work?

Tags: bacteriology, reproduction

So according to a PPT I'm reading, bacterial conjugation works by the two bacteria joining pili and exchanging plasmids. So how exactly do the plasmids get across the gap? If I understand this correctly, the pili are little hair-like things on the outside of the bacteria -- so unless the plasmids were actually able to somehow be pushed *through* the pili, there would be gap. Right?

The only other possibility I can think of would be that the membranes fused or something like that. But that comes with it's own whole set of problems.

How does this work?

Thanks!

evamvid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The donor cell retracts it pilus upon contact with another cell and both cells form a pore between the two cells, which allows the transfer of DNA. 
Take a look at the image, I think this makes it clearer (from the Wikipedia article on [Pili](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pilus)):

[image]

This has even be seen in an electron microscope:

[image]